# Why was my question on HTML5 video closed and moved to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Why was my HTML5 video encoding question moved to Stack Overflow? I could see it maybe going to the Audio & Video SE (although it is HTML5 and web browser specific), but it isn't about programming at all.

[How to deal with poor HTML5 video performance in Chrome?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/42335/how-to-deal-with-poor-html5-video-performance-in-chrome?noredirect=1)

I'm not new to Stack Exchange, and looked over existing questions on all these sites before posting here. There are other questions on HTML5 Video here, so not sure why it was moved.

Comment: Just a guess, but I think that because this has to do with a single video type and on site performance, it's considered more topical on Stack Overflow (because code would be needed to resolve the issue) rather than on Pro Webmasters. Hopefully a site mod will be able to provide a more robust answer :)

Comment: @Aarthi It is for both h.264 and WebM. It would have been nice if when it was closed and moved there was some feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Aarthi is correct. It was moved because StackOverflow is a better fit. The default comment left by the system describes this adequately which is why no other comment was left. We only leave comments when we feel it is necessary to clarify typically because of comments made in the question or experience with handling similar closures/migrations in the past.

Comment: I'm not sure Stack Overflow is a better fit... Is this a development question? Super User seems better. Still, it didn't get closed on SO, so maybe my interpretation is off.